# Fancybox-background changes, when active

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I have used Fancybox for a website i'm developing and i would be very thankful if anyone could answer my question:

How come big parts of my content dissappear, when a fancybox is active?

Browse down to the gallery section and press one and look at the background and you will understand what i am meaning.

I have used Fancybox for a long time under my delevopment process and it has worked before.

I assume that it has to do with the music players, but i'm not sure.

here's the code:

```
        <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>~ Dancing Lynx ~</title>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/smooth-scrolling.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/audioplugin/audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- initialize FancyBox -->
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
<script><!-- initialize audio.js -->
  audiojs.events.ready(function() {
    var as = audiojs.createAll();
  });
</script>
</head>


<body>
<div id="wrapper">

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="menu"><a href="#music-link" class="font">Music</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="#photos-link" class="font">Photos</a></li>
                <li id="logo"><a href="#main"class="font">Dancing Lynx</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="#gigs-link"class="font">Gigs</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="#gigs-link" class="font">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="main">

            <img id="bg" src="imgs/1425352_579721732082124_799005686_o.jpg"/>

            <header>
                <p class="font-style" id="index-title">~ Dancing Lynx ~</p>
                <div id="index-title"><a href="#music-link"><img id="enter" src="imgs/enter.png"/></a></div>
            </header>
        </div><!-- #main -->
        <div id="music">

            <p class="link" id="music-link"></p>
            <hr id="title-bar" class="top">
            <p class="font-style" id="music-title">Music</p>
            <hr id="title-bar" class="bottom">

                <ul>
                    <li><div class="song"><p class="song-title">City Lights</p><audio src="music/citylights.mp3" preload="auto" /></div></li>
                    <li><div class="song"><p class="song-title">One More Time</p><audio src="music/onemoretime.mp3" preload="auto" /></div></li>
                    <li><div class="song"><p class="song-title">She's A Killer</p><audio src="music/shesakiller.mp3" preload="auto" /></div></li>
                    <li><div class="song"><p class="song-title">Universe</p><audio src="music/universe.mp3" preload="auto" /></div></li>

                </ul>
            </div><!-- end #music -->
        <div class="section" id="photos">

            <p class="link" id="photos-link"></p><!-- Nav-Link -->

            <hr id="title-bar"><!-- Not marked with as a ".top", because those attributes are contained in the selector "#photos". Otherwise, the title-bar would get stretched 20px or not extend "the grey area"-->
            <p class="font-style" id="photos-title">Photos</p>
            <hr id="title-bar" class="bottom">
            <div id="photo-list">

                <ul>
                    <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="imgs/photos/1.jpg"><img id="image" src="imgs/photos/1.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="imgs/photos/1.jpg"><img id="image" src="imgs/photos/1.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="imgs/photos/1.jpg"><img id="image" src="imgs/photos/1.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="imgs/photos/1.jpg"><img id="image" src="imgs/photos/1.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="imgs/photos/1.jpg"><img id="image" src="imgs/photos/1.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="imgs/photos/1.jpg"><img id="image" src="imgs/photos/1.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="imgs/photos/1.jpg"><img id="image" src="imgs/photos/1.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="imgs/photos/1.jpg"><img id="image" src="imgs/photos/1.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="imgs/photos/1.jpg"><img id="image" src="imgs/photos/1.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="imgs/photos/1.jpg"><img id="image" src="imgs/photos/1.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="imgs/photos/1.jpg"><img id="image" src="imgs/photos/1.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="imgs/photos/1.jpg"><img id="image" src="imgs/photos/1.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="imgs/photos/1.jpg"><img id="image" src="imgs/photos/1.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="imgs/photos/1.jpg"><img id="image" src="imgs/photos/1.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="imgs/photos/1.jpg"><img id="image" src="imgs/photos/1.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="imgs/photos/1.jpg"><img id="image" src="imgs/photos/1.jpg"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- #photo-list -->
        </div><!-- #photos -->

        <div id="end">

        <div id="gigs">

            <p class="link" id="gigs-link"></p><!-- Nav-Link -->

            <hr id="title-bar" class="top">
            <p class="font-style">Gigs</p>
            <hr id="title-bar" class="bottom">
            <div id="gig-list">
                <object type="text/html" data="gig-list.txt">
                <param name="src" value="gig-list.txt">
                <param name="autoplay" value="false">
                <param name="autoStart" value="0">
<a href="gig-list.txt">Gigs</a>
</object>
            </div><!-- #gig-list -->

        </div><!-- #gigs -->

        <hr id="vertical-bar">

        <div id="contact">

            <p class="link" id="contact-link"></p>

            <hr id="title-bar" class="top">
            <p class="font-style">Contact</p>
            <hr id="title-bar" class="bottom">

            <ul>
                <li class="font" id="top"><p>Mail:</p><a href="mailto:email@domain.com">email@domain.com</a></li>
                <li class="font"><p>Phone:</p><p id="info">076-1232456</p></li>

            </ul>            
        </div><!-- End #contact -->    

        </div><!-- End #end -->

        <footer class="section">
                        <p class="font">Copyright: Dancing Lynx 2014</p>
                        <p class="font">Designed by: <a href="#">Adam Söderström</a></p>

                    </footer><!-- End footer -->

</div><!-- #wrapper -->


</body>
</html>
```

The style:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/*
    Additional Start
*/

html {
    height: 100%;   
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

p, a, li {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#vertical-bar {
    height: 645px;
    width: 1px; 
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.font {
    font-family: 'Lobster Two', Arial;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;    
}

.font-style {
    font-family: 'Lobster Two', Arial;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 108px;
    font-weight: 700;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;  
}

/*
    Link Preferences Start
        Settings for the Nav and "#enter"-links are set inside of these different selectors

*/

.link {
    position: absolute; 
}

#music-link, #photos-link { 
    margin-top: -120px;
}

#gigs-link, #contact-link {
    margin-top: -109px; 
}

/*
    Link Preferences End
*/

/*
    Title Bar Start
        The bars on the top and the bottom of the title of the different sections.
*/

#title-bar {
    width: 25%;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    color: #969696;
    background-color: #969696;
}

#photos #title-bar {
    width: 25%;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.top {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.bottom {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/*
    Title Bar End
*/

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF, #EEF); /* For Safari */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFF, #EEF); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFF, #EEF); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#FFF, #EEF); /* Standard syntax */
}

#bg {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.section {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    background-image: url(imgs/bg-noise.png);   
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


/*
    Additional End
*/

/*
    Nav Start (Shown on the top of the screen and works as a tool to navigate through the site)
*/

nav {
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF, #EEF); /* For Safari */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFF, #EEF); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFF, #EEF); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#FFF, #EEF); /* Standard syntax */
    box-shadow: 20px 0 20px #000;

}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
    font-size: 36px;    
}

#logo {
    font-size: 48px;    
}

/*
    Nav End
*/


/*
    Main Page Start (Shown when site is entered)
*/

#index-title {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 108px;
    color: #FFF;

}

#enter {
    width: 108px;
    margin-top: 150px;
}

/*
    Main Page End
*/

/*
    Music Page Start (Can be shown by scrolling down the page, pressing the circular "arrow"-button and by clicking on "Music" in the nav.
*/

#music {
    position: relative;
    width: 460px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 100px;

}

#music div {
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

.song-title {
    font-family: 'Lobster Two', Arial;
    text-decoration: underline;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

/*
    Music Page End
*/

/*
    Photos Page Start
*/

#photos {
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-image: url(imgs/bg-noise.png);
    background-image: url(imgs/bg-noise.png), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#333), to(#111)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background-image: url(imgs/bg-noise.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333, ##111); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background-image: url(imgs/bg-noise.png), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333, #111); /* FF3.6+ */
    background-image: url(imgs/bg-noise.png), -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333, #111); /* IE10 */
    background-image: url(imgs/bg-noise.png), -o-linear-gradient(top, #333, #111); /* Opera 11.10+ */   
    background-image: url(imgs/bg-noise.png), linear-gradient(top,#333, #111); /* W3C */
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000;
}

#photos-title {
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 0 5px 5px #000;
}

#photo-list {
    text-align: center; 
}

#photo-list ul {
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

#photo-list li {
    padding: 10px;      
}

#image {
    width: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #666;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #000;

}

/*
    Photos Page End
*/

/*
    Gigs and Contact Page Start
*/
/*
    Gigs and Contact Page End
*/

#end {
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 670px;
    background:url(imgs/bg-noise.png), #FFF;
    margin-bottom: 210px;
}

/*
    Gigs Page Start
*/

#gigs {
    width: 50%;
    height: 310px;
    float: left;
}

#gig-list {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#gig-list object {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 490px;
}
<!-- Height and width needs to be changed, if the list gets longer and wider. -->

/*
    Gigs Page End
*/

/*
    Contact Page Start
*/

#contact {
    width: 50%;
}

#contact ul{
    text-align: center; 
}

#contact li#top {
    padding: 0px;   
}

#contact li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}

#contact p, a {
    padding: 5px;   
}

#contact p {
    font-weight: 700;
}

#contact a, #info {
    color: #555;
    text-decoration:underline;  
}

#contact a:hover {
    color: #333;    
}

/*
    Contact Page End
*/

/*
    Footer Start
*/

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #333;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 210px; 
}

footer p, a {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #777;
}

footer a:hover {
    color: #999;
}

/*
    Footer End
*/
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean the content behind disappears?

Comment: Correct! I don't find a specific reason why it disappears.

Comment: 1). if the content of the link changes, the question becomes irrelevant. try posting here your relevant code. 2) try [validating](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://dancinglynx.adamsoderstrom.com/) your page to find potential issues. 3). Use either fancybox.js or fancybox.pack.js but not both.

Answer (score 0):

there is a class being added to the `html` tag called `fancybox-lock` which has `overflow: hidden !important` if you can find that in the stylesheet and remove it it should be all set.

Comment: The `fancybox-lock` class is a standard functionality of fancybox that can be toggled via an API option without messing with the plugin's original files. This answer may patch the current issue (in Chrome btw) but doesn't solve it or indicates the root cause of it.

Comment: Also correct! I'm going to publish the code, by the way.